# How to toggle between columns=60 and columns=[terminal_width]?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, terminal

My attempt so far:

```
" Essay mode
nnoremap <F5> :call Toggle_essay()<CR>
function Toggle_essay()
    if &linebreak
        setlocal columns=999
        setlocal nolinebreak
    else
        setlocal columns=60
        setlocal linebreak
    endif
endfunction
```

I want to map a single button to toggle between `columns=60`, and `columns=[terminal width]`, or whatever was the default when vim is first opened.

Issue is that `!tput cols` [always returns 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950595/get-columns-in-terminal-in-vim), `$COLUMNS` [are not exported to vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780483/lines-and-columns-environmental-variables-lost-in-a-script), and I'm uncertain about the behaviour for window splits.

**Surely there's a command equivalent to return columns to its default on-start behaviour?**

Comment: That sounds wrong. You should not change the `'columns'` setting it might break vim. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I want to use vim comfortably to write prose. I use my terminal fullscreen, which often results in a default column of about 200+, too wide to read and write long paragraphs of text comfortably. The only alternative to `columns`, if I'm not wrong, is `textwidth`; but that inserts unwanted newlines when it wraps text.

Comment: You could open empty vertical windows. That is how those distraction free plugins do it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I don't like the idea of that, unfortunately. I'm considering mapping the toggle to textwidth instead of columns, and mapping a 'save without linebreak-wraps' key with something like `nnoremap <F4> :textwidth=0<CR>gggq:w<CR>`

Comment: then that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `columns&vim` to set `columns` to its default value.

However, as explained [in the comments above](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/how-to-toggle-between-columns-60-and-columns-terminal-width#comment21967_12734), one should avoid changing columns. Rather, a combination of `textwidth=60`, `textwidth=999`, and `gggqG<C-o><C-o>`, where:

- `gg` – go to start;
- `gq` – apply current formatting to all;
- `G` – go to end;
- `<C-o>` – return cursor to previous position).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that explicitly storing the state in a buffer-local variable would be easiest. We also double this state variable to hold the previous value of `columns`, so it can be restored later:

```
fun! Toggle_essay()
        if !exists('b:essay_mode')
                let b:essay_mode = &columns
                setlocal columns=60 linebreak
        else
                setlocal nolinebreak
                let &l:columns =  b:essay_mode
                unlet b:essay_mode
        endif
endfun

nnoremap <F5> :call Toggle_essay()<CR>
```

Comment: I've found the solution to be `setlocal columns&vim`. Unfortunately, I can't answer my own question for the next 23 hours or so. My next problem here is that in a vertical split, this function sets the total columns of both windows =60, instead of each window being =60.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to set the display width of just a window outside of `columns` and `textwidth` @ning.